# Can not access object property in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I want to get value in list object in Angular.

Here is my component

```
 getAllStories():void{
    this.service.getAllStories().subscribe(
      ls => {
        this.StoriesList = ls;
        for ( let i  of this.StoriesList){
          console.log(i);
          console.log(i?.$Name)
         }
      }
    )
  }
```

This's my console log. when i show object it show exactly. but I get property of this object it show undefined.

[image]

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should write `console.log(i?.name)`.

Comment: Name is a private property and I can use get function to get this value. so '$' is need

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I don't know how '$' let you access a private property. If it's typesscript marked private, it won't let you access it with '$' + capital letter, and the native javascript private prefix is '#'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: thanks for your help. I have some mistake. I try your answer and it successful. thank you so much